# ViewBag is passing changed value PartialView

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, partial-views

I have a page (User.aspx) which displays list of users awaiting for acceptance. Page allows admin to accept users for organization by clicking on a button next to user's name. When admin click on button for any user in the list, it accepts the user at top of the list rather than selected user. I have checked the id's in Chrome Developer tool kit and it is passing right Id but when control hits the breakpoint in Action (AcceptUser) it shows the Id of first user in list. But looks like something is changing the value of ViewBag **(UserId)** in between. Can anyone please advice me how to fix this issue.

**Users.aspx**

```
<% foreach (var user in Model.UsersAwaitingAcceptance)
{ %>

    <a class="label label-SU-success" href="#accept" role="button" data-toggle="modal"><i class="icon-success icon-white"></i></a>
    <% Html.RenderPartial("AcceptUserDialog", Model.Accept, new ViewDataDictionary { { "OrgId", Model.OrgId }, { "UserId", user.Id } }); %>
<% } %>
```

**AcceptUserDialog.ascx**

```
<div id="accept">
    <% using (Html.BeginForm("AcceptUser", "Organization", new { userId = ViewBag.UserId, orgId = ViewBag.OrgId}, FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "zero-bottom form-horizontal" }))
    { %>
        // UserId is different here
        <%= ViewBag.UserId%>
        <%= ViewData["UserId"]%>

        // Above code is displaying different UserId
    <% } %>
<\div>
```

**OrganizationController**

```
public ActionResult AcceptUser(Guid userId, Guid orgId)
{
    // Logic here
}
```

Comment: Its a for each loop, what do you expect to get???..

Comment: I am expecting to get UserId of selected User rather than first user in the list.

Comment: i don't see any condition check inside the loop..

Comment: sorry If its not making any sense but what sort of condition check you are are talking about? I am expecting to have unique user.Id for each record in the list.

Comment: for each loop on Model.UsersAwaitingAcceptance object. As from name it will have a list of users. how are you selecting a particular user.

Comment: Passing on UserId to AcceptUserDialog as ViewDataDictionary object. and then in Dialog I have an option set. finally I am passing all values including UserId to Action.

Comment: Your code (in Razor) works fine and renders the `action` attribute correctly with different userId for each form. Does your form have a `submit` button? What is the `<a>` tag link for? Are you submitting via ajax. Do you have other scripts on the page?

Comment: Can you please show exact code of AcceptUserDialog. I am interested to see what you have got outside the @using statement.

Comment: Hi have a div with Id = accept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think problem is that div Id in AcceptUserDialog is not unique. It is same for all the buttons in list, if you make it unique for each row, it should work.

As I shown below, bring div into users.aspx page and put render dialogbox inside the div. then use UserId as div Id (`<div id="<%= user.Id%>">`) and href (`href="#<%= user.Id%>"`).

**Users.aspx**

```
<% foreach (var user in Model.UsersAwaitingAcceptance)
{ %>

    <a class="label label-SU-success" href="#<%= user.Id%>" role="button" data-toggle="modal"><i class="icon-success icon-white"></i></a>
<div id="<%= user.Id%>">
        <% Html.RenderPartial("AcceptUserDialog", Model.Accept, new ViewDataDictionary { { "OrgId", Model.OrgId }, { "UserId", user.Id } }); %>
<% } %>
<\div>
```

**AcceptUserDialog.ascx**

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm("AcceptUser", "Organization", new { userId = ViewBag.UserId, orgId = ViewBag.OrgId}, FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "zero-bottom form-horizontal" }))
{ %>
    // UserId is different here
    <%= ViewBag.UserId%>
    <%= ViewData["UserId"]%>

    // Above code is displaying different UserId
<% } %>
```

Try above, hopefully it will sort out your problem.

Answer (score 0):

It's going to take some debugging to verify this, but to start, add this to the view to debug that the ID's are the same by using the view source and looking at the form to make sure it isn't always passing the first ID for every entry.

You could also try accessing from ViewData directly as `ViewData["OrgId"]` and `ViewData["UserId"]` instead.

Comment: both ViewData and ViewBag are displaying same result which is different from desired Id. They are displaying userId of first user in list.